# Lustre: inode/files quota: dependent on striping?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, quota, inode, lustre

My understanding of the Lustre file system is that every file uses one inode on a metadata target (MDT), and then one inode per stripe on the object storage targets (OSTs). My question is, which of these numbers counts towards my file number (inode) quota? If I have 1000 files, each with (for example) four stripes, what will the output of the `files` be for `lfs quota`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears not to be the case. I ran a test by creating a striped file and deleting it; my inode count only changed by 1.